# proj_create_from_database when reading a raster with terra package

Tags: r, coordinate-systems, terra, epsg

I am trying to read several rasters using the terra package; first I get a vector with the file names and then I use the `rast()` function to read the files.

```
Land_variables_files <- list.files("Land_Variables1", pattern = '.tif$', full.names = T)
Land_variables_temp <- rast(Land_variables_files)
```

They should already be in EPSG 3035 and in fact this is the case, but when I wrote them I get this message on the screen

```
proj_create_from_database: datum not found
proj_create_from_database: ellipsoid not found
proj_create_from_database: prime meridian not found
```

I also tried to read them in EPSG 4326, but nothing changed.

What could be the problem An error regarding my reference system or the way I set it? I do my preliminary analyses in QGIS and save the rasters in EPSG 3035.

Using `show(Land_Variables_temp)` this is what I get:

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 1307, 1307, 7  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent      : 4496516, 4627216, 2494261, 2624961  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe (EPSG:3035) 
sources     : Agricultural_Fields.tif  
              Coniferous_Forests.tif  
              Deciduous_Forests.tif  
              ... and 4 more source(s)
names       : Agric~ields, Conif~rests, Decid~rests, Global_Model, Pastures, Settlements, ... 
min values  :          ? ,          ? ,          ? ,           64,       ? ,          ? , ... 
max values  :          ? ,          ? ,          ? ,          100,       ? ,          ? , ... '
```

I don't know why some variables have **?** as min/max values, but plotting them or taking them individually the values are okay.

on the other hand, using `crs()` this is the result:

```
[1] "PROJCRS[\"ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"ETRS89\",\n        ENSEMBLE[\"European Terrestrial Reference System 1989 ensemble\",\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1989\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1990\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1991\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1992\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1993\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1994\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1996\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1997\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 2000\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 2005\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 2014\"],\n            ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n            ENSEMBLEACCURACY[0.1]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4258]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Europe Equal Area 2001\",\n        METHOD[\"Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9820]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",52,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",10,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",4321000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",3210000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"northing (Y)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"easting (X)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Statistical analysis.\"],\n        AREA[\"Europe - European Union (EU) countries and candidates. Europe - onshore and offshore: Albania; Andorra; Austria; Belgium; Bosnia and Herzegovina; Bulgaria; Croatia; Cyprus; Czechia; Denmark; Estonia; Faroe Islands; Finland; France; Germany; Gibraltar; Greece; Hungary; Iceland; Ireland; Italy; Kosovo; Latvia; Liechtenstein; Lithuania; Luxembourg; Malta; Monaco; Montenegro; Netherlands; North Macedonia; Norway including Svalbard and Jan Mayen; Poland; Portugal including Madeira and Azores; Romania; San Marino; Serbia; Slovakia; Slovenia; Spain including Canary Islands; Sweden; Switzerland; Turkey; United Kingdom (UK) including Channel Islands and Isle of Man; Vatican City State.\"],\n        BBOX[24.6,-35.58,84.73,44.83]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",3035]]"
```

Using `gdal(lib = "all")` in return I get this:

```
gdal    proj    geos 
"3.5.2" "8.2.1" "3.9.3"
```

Thanks in advance to everyone

Comment: Can you please edit your question and `show(Land_variables_temp)` and `crs(Land_variables_temp)`?

Comment: Sorry, I actually didn't know how to write posts properly. Hope it is good now!

Comment: That helps a lot. Can you also add what is returned by `gdal(lib="all")`

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.6.53
r <- rast(nrow=2, ncol=2, crs="EPSG:3035", vals=1:4)
x <- writeRaster(r, "test.tif", overwrite=T)
x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 2, 2, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 180, 90  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe (EPSG:3035) 
#source      : test.tif 
#name        : lyr.1 
#min value   :     1 
#max value   :     4
```

Perhaps because I have different versions of the GDAL/PROJ libraries? I am using windows in this example.

```
gdal(lib="all")
#    gdal     proj     geos 
# "3.6.2"  "9.1.1" "3.11.1"
```

This problem has been [reported before](https://github.com/r-spatial/stars/issues/588). Sofar, it appears this message is only given with CRSs that use the ETRS datum. It was not resolved, but it does not seem to actually create a problem.

Comment: Now that I am looking at your answer I saw that I used different (older) version of the terra package and of gdal, proj and geos as well. I am putading the terra package to the latest version that I missed and then I'll try again. 
But may I ask you how can I update versions of GDAL/PROJ? Is it automatically done when updating terra?

Comment: If you are on windows these versions depend on the version of "terra" and you cannot change that.

Comment: Actually, I just uptaded `terra` but nothing changed, GDAL/PROJ version are still the same.